# Command and CommandParameter design

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command, commandparameter

Let's say you have a view-model that controls a media player. It has to offer standard control features like Star, Stop, Pause and Resume.

I'm thinking of two ways to design it in the view-model

1st Way : Every action has its own command.
- StartCommand
- StopCommand
- PauseCommand
- ResumeCommand

Every button in the view will be bound to it's related command.

2nd way : One single command with different commandparameters. PerformActionCommand and an enumeration that would look like

```
enum ActionEnum
{
  start, 
  stop,
  pause,
  resume
}
```

Which way do you think is preferable and for what reasons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case using separate commands is better. The commands are not very alike, so if you have one command handler, you will have to use a large switch statement inside and probably call separate methods.

Another reason is that with different commands you easily can have different conditions when those commands are enabled or not - for example Resume is enabled only when the player is paused.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Jogy writes I would also go for separate commands. In this way you can also use the built-in [wpf media commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mediacommands%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

This has some potential advantages:

- you don't need to write a class implementing [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for each command because it is already inside WPF
- Each media command is actually a [RoutedUICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routeduicommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which means it has the text propety that you can use as content for you button.
- You may take advantage of already built-in input gestures with some commands.